# Array out of bounds, when I try to swap values

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, swap

I am trying to swap values in a 2D array, but I get an "out of bounds" run time error.

What is wrong?

```
public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Q1
        int row = 3;
        int colum = 5;

        //Declare 2d array
        int [][] matrix = new int [row][colum];
        //Create array and input values
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter " + matrix.length + " rows and "
        + matrix[0].length + " colums: \n");
        for (row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
            for (colum = 0; colum < matrix[row].length ; colum++) {
                matrix[row][colum] = input.nextInt();
        }
            }
        System.out.println("\nMultiplication table");
        System.out.println("--------------------");

        //Print the array
        for (row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++ ) {
            for (colum = 0; colum < matrix[row].length; colum++ ) {
                System.out.printf("%4d", matrix[row][colum]);
            }

            System.out.println();
        }
        //Q2 - Make the values swapable
        Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("\n1: Modify a value. ");
        System.out.println("0: Exit the application");
        int selection = input1.nextInt();
        switch(selection) {
            case 0:
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            case 1:
                System.out.println("\nPlease enter the row you would like to change: "  );
                Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
                int changeRow = input2.nextInt();
                System.out.println("You entered: " + changeRow);
                System.out.println("Please enter the colum you would like to change: "  );
                Scanner input3 = new Scanner(System.in);
                int changeColum = input3.nextInt();
                System.out.println("You entered: " + changeColum);

    error--->   int temp = matrix[row][colum];
                matrix[row][colum] = matrix[changeRow][changeColum];
                matrix[changeRow][changeColum] = temp;

                System.out.println("The value in row " + changeRow + "and colum " + changeColum + "is now changed to " + temp);




                break;

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: P.S. Put the `public class Main {` in your code tag.

Comment: Are you trying to transpose a matrix?

Comment: I am trying to change a value in the matrix by entering row and colum number.

Comment: Please paste your error stacktrace and identify which line number in your code corresponds to the line number in your stacktrace.

Comment: This is the error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
        at mkrsassignment9.Main.main(Main.java:65)
Java Result: 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would have been easier to spot this if you had posted the stack trace of your exception. Here is my guess:

```
 int temp = matrix[row][colum];
```

What are the values of `row` and `column` here? They are last used before in the loop to print the array, thus you now have `row == matrix.length`, and `column == matrix[row].length` (with the `row` value one before).

Of course, this is outside of the permissible bounds of the array, and you get your IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `row` and `column` in your loops. Check the value of them AFTER the loops. I'm not sure if the increment is done and then the `<` check fails, but if it does, then this

```
int temp = matrix[row][colum];
```

is trying to find

```
matrix[3][5];
```

and as it starts at 0, that doesn't exists.

Answer (score 0):

When you get changeRow, changeColum inputs you need to create another array initialize with lengths and then assign the values by comparing previous array lengths.